# .NET Core 3.1 - Scoped service - Event handler invokes multiple times

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, event-handling, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created application in .net core 3.1, In which there are one singleton interface and its implementation class, which is receiving the TCP/IP socket message. There is one event handler in the class, which will be invoked once messages received on the socket.

```
public Class IncomingMessageHandler : IIncomingMessageHandler
{
    public event EventHandler<string> OnMessageReceived;

    private void InvokeMessageRecived(object sender, string message)
    {
        this.OnMessageReceived?.Invoke(this, message);
    }
}
```

There is one another service `TransactionService` class which is having dependency injected for the interface `IIncomingMessageHandler` and subscribe to `OnMessageReceived`.

```
public TransactionService(IIncomingMessageHandler incomingMessageHandler)
{
    this.incomingMessageHandler = incomingMessageHandler;
    this.incomingMessageHandler.OnMessageReceived += this.IncomingMessageHandler_OnMessageReceived;
}
```

From this class, I am initiating the transaction and once a transaction started I will receive the messages into `IncomingMessageHandler` and `OnMessageReceived` invokes, Messages I am storing into the List for further processing.

Now `TransactionService` is the Scoped service class and for each API request new object will be created, Now If there are multiple requests are made, for each `TransactionService` would subscribe to  `OnMessageReceived` and it invokes multiple time because there are multiple objects initiated and override the List of messages.

I can't register `TransactionService` as singleton due to some other limitations.

Is there any other way through which `OnMessageReceived` gets invoked only for the specific service object?

I have tried to un-subscribe the `OnMessageReceived`, but still, this issue will occur for multiple API requests at the same time.

Comment: You have a Queuing System where you have inputs from multiple sources and one API to process the data.  You have to handle this like any other Queuing System.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_management_system

Comment: Thank you for comment, I am not sure if this is related to queueing or not, Also I cannot restrict API access for each individual and apply any queue mechanism.

Comment: What you are describing is a Queuing System that has a Type (FIFO/Priority), Singleton/Parallel, and locking (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are binding to an event and not unbinding when finished, it causes a bit of a memory leak - the instances of `TransactionService` live on in other references and can't be GC'd. You should have `TransactionService` implement `IDisposable` and unbind it in the `Dispose` method. That removes the reference from the event in `IncomingMessageHandler` and you won't have duplicate calls.

Aside: I tried something very similar and I actually found using Reactive Extensions made for a much better pattern overall.

Comment: I have tried to dispose the ```TransactionService``` using IDisposable, now ```TransactionService``` disposed. but, when I tried to perform the concurrent API Request at that time it performs the duplicate calls and overrides the existing stored details from the previous call.

Comment: @MohsinTolat that’s a separate question your pattern is a bit flawed

Comment: Yup I agree with you @Daniel A. White, Is there anything else I can apply to resolve this flaw?